# pthreads: using multiple threads to calculate successive prime numbers

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I am trying to get the example code to work such that multiple threads will calculate the sum of successive prime numbers (note that the original author's algorithm for successive prime calculation is very inefficient). So far, running unit tests shows that the output is inconsistent, i.e. it will change slightly each time I run the program. I will post the modified source code in C, along with output for debugging purposes.

Source:

```
/************************************************************************
 * Code listing from "Advanced Linux Programming," by CodeSourcery LLC  *
 * Copyright(C) 2001 by New Riders Publishing                           *
 * See COPYRIGHT for license information.                               *
 ***********************************************************************/

/*
 * Modified By : Dylan Gleason
 * Class       : CST 352 - Operating Systems
 * Date        : 10/18/2012
 */

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG 0  /* Set to 1 to enable debug statements */

/* global variables to be accessed by each thread */
int current_sum = 2;
int primes_to_compute = 0;

/* create mutex for ensuring serial access to global data */
int thread_flag;
pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

/* print the thread info for debugging purposes */
void print_thread_info() 
{
   printf("Current thread ID        : %u\n",(unsigned int*)pthread_self());
   printf("Current sum of primes    : %d\n", current_sum);
   printf("Current prime to compute : %d\n\n", primes_to_compute);
}

/* initialize the mutex and return an integer value to determine if
   initialization failed or not */
int initialize_mutex()
{
   int success = 1;

   if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) == 0 &&
      pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL) == 0)
      success = 0;
   thread_flag = 0;

   return success;
}

/* set the value of the wait thread flag to the value which the client
   passes */
void set_thread_flag(int is_waiting)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);   /* lock mutex */

   /* set the wait flag value, and then signal in case the prime
      function is blocked, waiting for flag to become set. However,
      prime function can't actually check flag until the mutex is
      unlocked */
   thread_flag = is_waiting;
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond);   
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); /* unlock mutex */
}

void in_wait()
{
   while(!thread_flag)
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
}


/* Compute successive prime numbers(very inefficiently). Return the
   Nth prime number, where N is the value pointed to by *ARG. */
void* compute_prime(void* arg)
{   
   while(1)
   {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      in_wait();
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

      int sum;
      int factor;
      int is_prime = 1;

      set_thread_flag(0);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      sum = current_sum;

      if(DEBUG)
      {
         printf("First lock\n");
         print_thread_info();
      }

      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
      set_thread_flag(1);          /* tell next thread to go! */

      /* wait until ready-flag is released from current thread */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      in_wait();
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

      /* Test primality by successive division. */
      for(factor = 2; factor < sum; ++factor)
      {  
         if(sum % factor == 0)
         {
            is_prime = 0;
            break;
         }
      }

      /* Is this the prime number we're looking for? */
      if(is_prime)
      {
         int number;

         set_thread_flag(0);
         pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

         /* only decrement primes_to_compute if is greater than zero! */
         if(primes_to_compute > 0)
         {
            --primes_to_compute;
         }       
         if(DEBUG)
         {
            printf("Second lock\n");
            print_thread_info();
         }

         number = primes_to_compute;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
         set_thread_flag(1);

         pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
         in_wait();
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

         if(number  == 0)
         {
            set_thread_flag(0);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            void* sum =(void*) current_sum;

            if(DEBUG)
            {
               printf("Third lock\n");         
               print_thread_info();
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            set_thread_flag(1);
            return sum;
         }
      }

      set_thread_flag(0);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      ++current_sum;

      if(DEBUG)
      {
         printf("Fourth lock\n");
         print_thread_info();
      }

      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
      set_thread_flag(1);
   }

   return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int prime;
   pthread_t tid[5];   

   /* Check command-line argument count */
   if(argc != 2)
   {
      printf("Error: wrong number of command-line arguments\n");
      printf("Usage: %s <integer>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Check to see if mutex initialized correctly */
   if(initialize_mutex() != 0)
   {
      printf("Mutex initialization failed.\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   primes_to_compute = atoi(argv[1]);
   printf("Successive primes to be computed: %d\n\n", primes_to_compute);

   /* Execute five different threads to calculate the prime summation */
   int t = 0;
   set_thread_flag(1);

   for(t; t < 5; ++t)
      pthread_create(&tid[t], NULL, &compute_prime, NULL);

   /* Wait for the prime number thread to complete, then get result. */
   t = 0;
   for(t; t < 5; ++t)
      pthread_join(tid[t],(void*) &prime);

   /* Print the largest prime it computed. */
   printf("The %dth prime number is %d.\n", atoi(argv[1]), prime);

   return 0;
}
```

Unit test (executing program five times):

```
Test successive primes up to 100:

Successive primes to be computed: 100
The 100th prime number is 547.

Successive primes to be computed: 100
The 100th prime number is 521.

Successive primes to be computed: 100
The 100th prime number is 523.

Successive primes to be computed: 100
The 100th prime number is 499.

Successive primes to be computed: 100
The 100th prime number is 541.
```

Note that the output of non-threaded version if the number for successive primes to calculate is `100`, the result will always be `541`. Clearly I am not able to grok the correct usage of the mutexes above - if someone has more experience in this area I would be very grateful! Also, **please note** that I am not concerned with the efficiency/correctness of the actual prime number algorithm, but rather the algorithm for making sure that the threads execute properly with consistent results.

Comment: I haven't read your entire code, but if you're computing *successive* prime numbers with a sieve algorithm, that sounds like an inherently serial process.  If you have several threads working on computing prime numbers successively then you'll need to invest (waste) a LOT of time and effort to ensure that it behaves as if it were entirely single-threaded.  Your best bet would be a different algorithm probably.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I may not have been too clear in the description above, but the intent is not to use an efficient algorithm for calculating primes, but rather to see how threads work and get them working to produce consistent results.

Comment: Actually your algorithm is not a sieve and does not depend on previous state, please disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking at your program I think I see what's going on.

You have a race condition, and a pretty bad one.  Which number you're on is determined by the `current_sum` variable.  You access it at the beginning of each loop, but don't increment it until the end of the loop.  You need to set and then increment it at the same time within the same mutex lock, otherwise two different threads will be able to pull the same value, and if they pull the same prime value then that prime will be counted twice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, so at the beginning of the first `while` loop, after I assign `sum = current_sum`, I should then increment the `current_sum` value?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. :)

Comment: Thank you. I also noticed that I am still returning `current_sum` after casting to a `void*` - will need to change that too.

Comment: Still seems to produce inconsistent results - I will look over it some more and try to determine where else there might be a race condition occurring.

Comment: I... really don't get why you're casting to a `void*` there.  I also don't get why you aren't just accessing `current_sum` directly rather than relying on the output of join.  That might simplify your code significantly while making it easier to predict the results.

Comment: would I need to use an additional lock to return `current_sum`?

Comment: don't even return `current_sum`, just return 0.  And then in your main thread display `current_sum` rather than `prime`

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18260/discussion-between-omnipotententity-and-dylan)